# Matlab's OpenCV Interface Example Not Working (Run Oriented FAST and Rotated BRIEF (ORB) Detector Example)

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv

I installed OpenCV interface for matlab by using command `visionSupportPackages` in order to run the `testORBFeaturesOCV.m` script which is covered in their [official tutorial](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ug/opencv-interface.html) under the heading "Run Oriented FAST and Rotated BRIEF (ORB) Detector Example".

I compiled the opencv cpp files fine although there was a warning the opencv was compiled with VS2012 while matlab (2015a) uses VS2010.

However, when I run the `testORBFeaturesOCV.m` script, it crashes when it reaches the opencv functions. It doesn't produce any crash log files.

On the other hand, when I ran the Template Matching Example from the same tutorial it produces crash log files. Here are first 27 lines of the file:

```
Access violation detected at Wed Oct 19 17:43:21 2016

Configuration:
  Crash Decoding      : Disabled
  Crash Mode          : continue (default)
  Current Graphics Driver: Unknown hardware 
  Default Encoding    : windows-1252
  Graphics card 1     : Intel Corporation ( 0x8086 ) Intel(R) HD Graphics 5500 Version 20.19.15.4444
  Graphics card 2     : Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. ( 0x1002 ) AMD Radeon (TM) R5 M330 Version 20.19.0.32837
  Host Name           : Lenovo-PC
  MATLAB Architecture : win64
  MATLAB Root         : C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Production Server\R2015a
  MATLAB Version      : 8.5.0.197613 (R2015a)
  OpenGL              : hardware
  Operating System    : Microsoft Windows 10 Home Single Language
  Processor ID        : x86 Family 6 Model 61 Stepping 4, GenuineIntel
  Virtual Machine     : Java 1.7.0_60-b19 with Oracle Corporation Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM mixed mode
  Window System       : Version 10.0 (Build 14393)

Fault Count: 1

Abnormal termination:
Access violation
```

I tried running MATLAB as administrator but it didn't work. Any ideas on how to make it work?

The image below shows error after running ORB Detector Example:

[image: OpenCV interface not working]

Comment: When Matlab crashes it generates a log file. Take a look at the file and will probably contain some info about what it's making it crash.

Comment: Updated question to include log files. It says access violation but even running as administrator doesn't fix it. Any suggestions?